# Why did Seven of Nine become human so aggressively?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg, seven-of-nine

The Voyager episode [The Gift](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Gift_%28episode%29) is, for all intents and purposes, the story of how Seven became human. Multiple times in the first 10-15 minutes the Doctor comments on how aggressively her human half is reasserting itself, rejecting the implants and causing medical issues.

But Why did Seven's organic components re-surge the way they did once her link to the Collective was severed? In the Next Generation episode [I Borg](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/I_Borg_%28episode%29), the Borg Hugh did not appear to suffer from any implant rejection.

Was Seven an aberration, fitted with sub-par implants or blessed with a particularly strong constitution? Or was Hugh abnormal in someway, able to go long periods of time without any implant rejection?

Comment: There was the whole Unimatrix Zero situation that made Seven fairly unique (at least compared to the others who'd been disconnected from the Collective), but I don't think any connections have ever been made...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is [strongly hinted](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dark_Frontier_%28episode%29) that Seven was deliberately planted amongst the *Voyager* crew and had her humanity strengthened as part of a long-term Borg plan to assimilate humanity. The Borg Queen even described Seven as "unique," so there is obviously something about Seven's physiology which makes her useful to the Borg in her own right, not just as another drone.

Comment: Hmm, there is that. Assuming that the Queen wasn't just being manipulative.

Comment: At another point in the same episode the Queen attempts to lie to Seven, and Seven catches her easily. Apparently the Borg are terrible liars, due to the fact that they have no experience with it. So while the Queen is likely capable of lying, it's doubtful she could actually lie to Seven and get away with it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe they were actively removing parts of 7s borg physiology they removed her borg plating so she looked more human among other things, I dont remember them doing that to Hugh so its probable that some piece of technology they removed had a suppressor function

also theres a time factor involved as well I believe 7 was disconnected longer than Hugh was before her physiology reasserted itself

Comment: They didn't really begin to remove the implants until after the Doctor said they were being rejected.